# DriverManager cant be found, underlines red and prompts me to create class DriverManager

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException
{
    //define the fields
    String username = "root";
    String password = "Otiwah0771";
    String jdbcURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employeedirectory";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

    try
    {

    //Get the Print Writer object
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Connecting to databace"+jdbcURL);

    //load the Driver 
    Class.forName(driver);

    //Get the connection
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL,username,password);

    //Close the connection
    connection.close();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

** Using Netbeans 11.2 **

I have added mysql connector jar and yet the issue persists (DriverManager symbol cant be found)

Comment: Did you import `java.sql.DriverManager`? Or do you have a `module-info.java` in your project, and that file does not contain `requires java.sql`?

Comment: The thing is i cant import if it doesn't exist, i just downloaded the java sql api jar and added it to my libraries and now its working

Comment: As I said, you are likely using a modular project (which means it has a `module-info.java` at the root of your sources). If you create a modular Java application or  library, you must add `requires java.sql;` to this `module-info.java` file, otherwise you don't get access to the JDBC API. The alternative is to not create a modular Java application.

Comment: i think i might have created a module project @MarkRotteveel added requires java.sql;

Answer (score 0):

Your problem of not being able to import `DriverManager` can be explained if you have created a modular project, and did not explicitly require the `java.sql` module.  If you don't explicitly require `java.sql`, you don't get access to the JDBC API, even though it is included with Java.

To fix this, edit `module-info.java` in the default package (or: the root of your source packages) and add the following line to the body of the module:

```
requires java.sql;
```

For example

```
module examplemodule {
    requires java.sql;
}
```

You should now be able to import `java.sql.DriverManager`.

Alternatively, don't use a modular project (ie use a project without `module-info.java`).

As an aside, your code seems to be a servlet, it is generally a bad practice to use `DriverManager` directly in a web application. Instead use a `javax.sql.DataSource` backed by a connection pool to create and reuse connections.

Answer (score 0):

Newer drivers of MySQL use the com.cj.mysql.jdbc.Driver class. Class.forname() is no longer required in these newer versions as the connection object will find it itself but see what works for you

Answer (score -1):

The issue is jdbc-api-1.4.jar is not part of the libraries and therefore cannot import java.sql.Driver.class. download jdbc-api-1.4.jar from[jdbc api](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjdbcapi14jar.htm) 
- add it to the libraries and it works

Comment: JDBC is part of Java SE, so you don't need to download anything to be able to use it. If this solved the problem for you, then likely you are using a modular project and did not add a dependency to `java.sql` in the `module-info.java` file.

Comment: if i may is jdbc part of Java ee ?

Comment: JDBC is part of Java SE. It is included with a normal Java install. You don't need to download it (especially not a version of the API that is 18 years out of date).